# PDO Class not found when being called from within a namespace class

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces

I am working on a local development using MAMP Pro. As of this morning (Monday), the script installed for searching is not working, although it was working Friday evening when I left. I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'AjaxLiveSearch\core\PDO' not found in /Users/judson/Sites/rptoffice.local/lib/thirdparty/livesearch/Handler.php:275
```

Line 275:

```
$wtt = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The script in question is using names spaces and calls the database connection like this:

```
namespace AjaxLiveSearch\core;

$DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
file_exists(__DIR__ . $DS . 'DB.php') ? require_once __DIR__ . $DS . 'DB.php' : die('DB.php not found');
file_exists(__DIR__ . $DS . 'Config.php') ? require_once __DIR__ . $DS . 'Config.php' : die('Config.php not found');

private function __construct($dbInfo) {
        try {
            // For MySQL version 5.5.3 or greater you can use 'utf8mb4' encoding instead of 'utf8'
            self::$db = new \PDO(
                'mysql:host=' . $dbInfo['host'] . ';dbname=' . $dbInfo['database'] . ';charset=utf8',
                $dbInfo['username'],
                $dbInfo['pass']
            );

            self::$db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // To prevent PDO sql injection
            self::$db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } 
        catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I have checked and PDO is running, and in php.ini I have:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Something to note is that the database connection and main site is working fine, and uses PDO. It also uses the variable $db, so not sure if that is causing a conflict. Again, this all worked on Friday.

Comment: You're missing the backslash prefix... `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. Alternately add `use PDO;`

Comment: @Phil - Thanks that was it. I thought I had tried that. Thanks again!